# How do I use a 5 pin potentiometer?

Tags: potentiometer, reverse-engineering, pinout

I have a 5 pin trim pot I desoldered from an old board. I am assuming maybe it is a dual gang poteniometer or something with a common ground pin. Does anyone have any ideas what the actual pinouts could be and how I can test it to check? There is number on the side that says 2889, but I am not sure what that means (I doubt its a part number). Here are some images of it: [image]

[image]

Comment: My guess it that it is a coil/transformer (one side centre-tapped) from an old radio, withg an adjustable coild.

Comment: Usually you can remove the metal case easily, and then it is revealed that this is a trim inductor.

Comment: FYI, I would guess the markings are a date code.  28th week of 1989.

Comment: It's definitely not a pot and definitely is an RF inductor or transformer. Try searching for a company called coilcraft or even murata.

Comment: It was from a radio actually, but there were a ton of these everywhere. At least 15 or so. Could it be an RF inductor then?

Comment: Yeah the word coil is actually engraved into the top of it... huh should have taken out my magnifying glass earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it's a variable-frequency tank circuit. Try this for a test.

Measure the resistance between the 3 in-line pins. Probably you'll find that the center pin has equal resistance to the 2 ends. Now look at the other two pins. If they read open, then most likely those pins are a variable capacitor, and the adjustment slot varies the capacitance. Basically, it looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu2Yws.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Ignore the + on the cap symbol.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a an IF transformer.

This will usually have two windings with one being tapped.

Depending upon the particular application it will probably have a capacitor across the tapped winding to make it resonate at either 10.7MHz or 455kHz.

kevin